ClosedChannelException when forwarding request with Gateway MVC
I want to:

Send a POST request to a Gateway MVC server
Make the gateway forward the request to a mocked endpoint

(everything is happening on the same host)
However, I get a ClosedChannelException exception when trying to execute my plan
What is my mistake?
Note. When reproducing, be sure to include a Spring Cloud Gateway MVC dependency as well as a WireMock dependency (standalone)
import java.net.URI;

import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.WireMock;
import com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.junit5.WireMockTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.HandlerFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.GatewayRouterFunctions.route;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.handler.HandlerFunctions.http;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.predicate.GatewayRequestPredicates.method;
import static org.springframework.cloud.gateway.server.mvc.predicate.GatewayRequestPredicates.path;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT,
        properties = "server.port=8080")
@WireMockTest(httpPort = 8090)
public class GenericTest {
    private static final String BODY = "body";

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    void test() {

        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.post("/post-to-service")
                .willReturn(WireMock.ok().withBody("response-body")));

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                "http://localhost:8080/post-to-gateway",
                BODY, String.class);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    static class ComplimentingConfig {
        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
            return new RestTemplate();
        }

        @Bean
        public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> postRouterFunction() {
            return route("post-route")
                    .route(path("/post-to-gateway")
                                    .and(method(HttpMethod.POST)),
                            http("http://localhost:8090")
                    )
                    .filter(rewritePathHandlerFunction("/post-to-service"))
                    .build();
        }
        
        private HandlerFilterFunction<ServerResponse, ServerResponse> rewritePathHandlerFunction(String newPath) {
            return (request, next) -> {
                URI newUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(request.uri())
                        .replacePath(newPath)
                        .build()
                        .toUri();
                ServerRequest newRequest = ServerRequest.from(request)
                        .uri(newUri)
                        .build();
                return next.handle(newRequest);
            };
        }
    }
}

ERROR 8036 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:8090/post-to-service": null] with root cause

java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null

It may have to do with Tomcat, I guess
UPD
This is interesting. I removed the body altogether and mocked a GET endpoint instead (ignore the fact that the path is still called "post-to-service")
        WireMock.stubFor(WireMock.get("/post-to-service")
                .willReturn(WireMock.ok()));

        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(
                "http://localhost:8080/post-to-gateway",
                String.class);
// ...
            return route("post-route")
                    .route(path("/post-to-gateway"),
                            http("http://localhost:8090"))
                    .filter(rewritePathHandlerFunction("/post-to-service"))
                    .build();

Result:
ERROR 10880 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8090/post-to-service": Can't get stream 1: java.io.IOException: /127.0.0.1:51610: GOAWAY received] with root cause

java.io.IOException: /127.0.0.1:51610: GOAWAY received
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.Http2Connection.handleGoAway(Http2Connection.java:1008) ~[java.net.http:na]

Notice a weird port (@WireMockTest(httpPort = 8090) was still in place)
